# How does assembly code translate to bytes? (amd64)

Tags: assembly, compilation

I'm trying to create a program that can translate strings of assembly code, i.e. converting

```
mov rax, rcx
mov rbx, 00h
cmp rax, rbx
je _rax_is_zero
```

into

[image]

which I used a website to do.

My problem is that I can't find any good documentation on how they are converted. Where can I see how the states of specific bits affect what instruction it is interpreted as?

Comment: See the Official Intel Documentation - eg. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.html or such and such. There are also 'distilled down' references found on line, and the older-older Intel references have much less .. "extra" stuff covered.

Comment: Should try more searches .. here is (an older, simpler) reference - https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~410/doc/intel-isr.pdf . Also, I'm sure one could find reference code for various assemblers (including those used for university classes/projects) without much effort ..

Comment: NASM and YASM are open source; you don't need to write your own.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for links to assembler docs.  See also https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding for a direct answer to your question, or of course Intel's manuals.

Comment: If you need a detailed peek how are assembly statements translated to machine code, you can inspect €ASM source online at https://euroassembler.eu/easource/